# Is there a lazy javascript download/interpretion that is triggered when a required function is called?

Tags: javascript

Say I have two separate blocks of JavaScript, script A and script B. In script B I call function a from script A, but script A hasn't yet been downloaded and/or interpreted. The library should resolve the dependency (using a table or something), trigger the interpretation of A and then perform the desired function call.

This might be useful sometimes (usually not, I know).

I have read [this article](http://wonko.com/post/painless_javascript_lazy_loading_with_lazyload) and know about the [Lazy Ready plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/LazyReady), but they don't seem to do the dependency resolution stuff that I would like to have.

Comment: So you would like to catch when an undefined function is called, and when that happens, pause the execution of the caller, load the script that defines the function, and then resume execution?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Exacly. You might want to edit my question to improve clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do it by including dummy functions that contain the logic to download the scripts:

```
function funcA(parameter) {
  var source = loadSynchronousAjax( 'url for script A' ); // whatever function you usually use to load data synchronously
  eval( source ); // this will replace the funcA symbol with the proper implementation 
  return funcA( parameter );
}
```

You will have to define the dependencies yourself, but the resolution should take care of itself. If funcA (the real one) uses another dummy function it would be loaded the same way.

Extracting common code:

```
function lazyFunction( obj, url, name ) {
  obj[name] = function () {
    var source = loadSynchronousAjax( url );
    eval( source ); 
    return obj[name].apply( obj, arguments );  
  };
}

lazyFunction( window, 'url for script A', 'funcA' );
lazyFunction( window, 'url for script B', 'funcB' );
lazyFunction( window, 'url for script B', 'funcC' );
```

This would define two scripts with three functions that are loaded lazily.

I should add that I don't think it's a good idea to load the scripts synchronously, but if lazy functions should look like normal functions there isn't much choice.

If you can change the signature of the lazy functions to asynchronous calls this might actually be a worthwhile pattern.

Answer (score 0):

They require that the JS be written to conform with their patterns, but options include:

- [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)
- [YUI Loader](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/yui-loader-ext.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're after but LABjs is a script loader and could do what you're looking for, a quick example from the docs

```
<script>
   $LAB
   .script("framework.js").wait()
   .script("plugin.framework.js")
   .script("myplugin.framework.js").wait()
   .script("init.js").wait();
</script>
```

It will allow you to load the files but not execute them so you can wait for the depedencies to be loaded as well. Hope that makes sense.
http://labjs.com

Comment: I think this is not what I want. I want execution to start and the dependencies to be loaded only if they are really needed at a certain point in the code. That would surely require using a hook or something.

Comment: Yeah, that's not gonna work with my answer. Can I ask you why you want to load your scripts **only when** you need them ?

Comment: Because I might need them only in vary rare use cases. Loading them every time would hurt more than the wait that happens once in a while when I really need them.